# Game Engine - Actions dependent on an integer

Tags: game-engine

I'm attempting to put together a turn based combat system that requires the game engine to look at an integer titled Speed to dictate which character goes first. The problem I'm having is how do I have it send a message to specific actor based on speed?

So far I have it set up in my head as:
Empty Object copies Speed integer from both characters
After Confirmation of action, message sent to Empty Object
Empty Object compares Player 1 speed and Player 2 speed

This is part I have trouble with. How do I have it send the attack message to the one with the higher speed then AFTER the first one attacks, send a second message to the remaining player?

Comment: Empty Object Receives Speed integer from Objects named P1 and P2
1.[Set to Tap]Message"Confirmed Attack"~P1S>P2S~Message sent "P1S Attack"/Property Integer "P1S" set to 0
2.[Set to Tap]Message"Confirmed Attack"~P2S>P1S~Message sent "P2S Attack"/Property Integer "P2S" set to 0
3.[Set to Tap]Message"Confirmed Attack"~P1S=0 AND P2S=0~Property Copy "P1S Speed" from P1 Object/Property Copy"P2S Speed" from P2 Object
4.[Set to Tap]Message"P1S Attack"/Message"Delay P1S Attack"~AND ~Delay 50 Logic Ticks
5.[Set to Tap]Message"P2S Attack"/Message"Delay P2S Attack"~AND ~Delay 50 Logic Ticks

Comment: It took a lot of characters to make that and I had to delete spaces so I apologize for how tight nit it is. You can see where it says 1. and 2. and 3. and so on. Those are basically to dictate each logic brick. it's just it got smashed together like that and not spaced paragraph like I had it. Essentially the player objects will send the delay message so that a delay happens to allow time for actions to complete before the logic bricks continue.

Comment: So now comes the question. Will this work essentially for my original problem?